# Why it doesn't save changes into datatable from datagridview?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, datatable, dataadapter

I have binded `datagridview` with `datatable` (*Growns*). My main goal is, that user can work with `datagridview` (*dataGridView1*), filling and updating data and when `button` *SAVE* is clicked, all data would be saved into datatable, because I need it for further work.

Everything works fine, **exept saving data into datatable**. What am I doing wrong?

Here is my code:

```
private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'tekmovalecDataSet.Odrasli' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        this.grownsTableAdapter.Fill(this.competitorDataSet.Odrasli);
    }

private void buttonSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        if (EmptySpace())
        {
                CompetitorDataSet.OdrasliRow newGrownsRow = competitorDataSet.Growns.NewGrownsRow();
                newGrownsRow.StN = textStN.Text;
                newGrownsRow.Name = textN.Text;
                newGrownsRow.Surname = textSN.Text;
                newGrownsRow.Club = textC.Text;
                newGrownsRow.YBirth = textYB.Text;
                competitorDataSet.Growns.Rows.Add(OdrasliNova);
                competitorDataSet.Growns.AcceptChanges();

                this.dataGridView1.DataSource = competitorDataSet.Growns;
                this.Validate();
                this.grownsBindingSource.EndEdit();
                if (dataGridView1.BindingContext[competitorDataSet.Growns] != null)
                {
                    dataGridView1.BindingContext[competitorDataSet.Growns].EndCurrentEdit();
                }
                this.grownsTableAdapter.Update(competitorDataSet.Odrasli);
                this.grownsTableAdapter.Adapter.AcceptChangesDuringUpdate = true;
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Fill ALL data about competitor!");
        }
    }
```

P.S.: When I manually fill `datatable`, on form open `datagridview` is filled, so `datatable` and `datagridview` are connected I suppose...

P.S.2.: bool `EmptySpace` works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you set `this.Update(competitorDataSet.Odrasli);` the `TableAdapter` updates the changes from `DataTable` (news, deleted, updated rows) to the database.

Since you call `competitorDataSet.Growns.AcceptChanges();` **before** `TableAdapter.Update`, all changes in the table are already accepted and TableAdapter has nothing to update.

So just remove

```
competitorDataSet.Growns.AcceptChanges();
```

Also, if you set `this.grownsTableAdapter.Adapter.AcceptChangesDuringUpdate = true` **before** `grownsTableAdapter.Update(competitorDataSet.Odrasli);`, the changes will be accepted and so you don't need to accept changes yourself (and it seems to me that default value is True so I am not sure this line is required)

Comment: Thanks! It works now =) It seemed that I wanna be on safe side and so I was adding to much code while I didn't understand it. So, thanks for explanation and solution =)

Answer (score 0):

You are not editing the data with the datagridview, you are changing the dataset using the textboxes, I think this is your example with the manual fill...

I will presume that the code you want to use to update the database begins at this line:

```
this.dataGridView1.DataSource = competitorDataSet.Growns;
```

I suspect your problem is in the following code block (explanations in code comments):

```
//why rebind the datagridview?
//this line should be removed
this.dataGridView1.DataSource = competitorDataSet.Growns;

//why call this here? validation should be done prior 
//to adding the new row to the datatable
//this line should be removed
this.Validate();

this.grownsBindingSource.EndEdit();
if (dataGridView1.BindingContext[competitorDataSet.Growns] != null)
{
dataGridView1.BindingContext[competitorDataSet.Growns].EndCurrentEdit();
}

//reverse the order of these 2 lines
this.grownsTableAdapter.Update(competitorDataSet.Odrasli);
this.grownsTableAdapter.Adapter.AcceptChangesDuringUpdate = true;
/* like this:
this.grownsTableAdapter.Adapter.AcceptChangesDuringUpdate = true;
this.grownsTableAdapter.Update(competitorDataSet.Odrasli);
 */
```

If this does not solve your problem, please post the binding code for your datagriview.

Comment: Sadly, this doesn't work. I bind it with designer so I suppose, this is what you want to know (code in Form.Designer): `//grownsBindingSource: 
            this.grownsBindingSource.DataMember = "Growns";
            this.grownsBindingSource.DataSource = this.competitorDataSet;//competitorDataSet:
this.competitorDataSet.CaseSensitive = true;
            this.competitorDataSet.DataSetName = "CompetitorDataSet";`
and in datagridview line:
`this.dataGridView1.DataSource = this.odrasliBindingSource;`

Comment: Here: and in datagridview line: this.dataGridView1.DataSource = this.odrasliBindingSource; shouldn't it be  this.dataGridView1.DataSource = this.grownsBindingSource; ?

Comment: My fault, didn't change it in english for better understanding. However,  this is not the case. Still doesn't work. Is there any "trick" in properties for datagridview or datatable?

Comment: Did you try Chris's suggestion?

Comment: Yes, I overlooked AcceptChanges after row adding. Thanks for help, now it works =)