# Visual C#, Value of datagridview cell that is on focus is not submitted when I hit the submit button

Tags: c#, datagridview

I am unable to submit the value of a cell that is on focus when I hit a submit button that I have created. Is there a command to submit the value of a datagridview that has its cell on focus.

The value is only submitted when I hit enter and thus is when its focus is gone.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why it doesn't save changes into datatable from datagridview?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17807373/why-it-doesnt-save-changes-into-datatable-from-datagridview)

Answer (score 0):

I am supposing you are trying to submit the Selected Value of a Cell into a **TextBox**, all you have to do is to trigger the textbox key down event and write..

```
private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
  {
    if(e.KeyCode==Keys.Enter)
    {
      txtID.Text = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value.ToString();
      //do whatever you want to
    }
  }
```